# Optimize MySQL indexes to query in less than a second

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain, sql-execution-plan

The query time for a very simple min-max no-join no-nesting SQL is taking more than 2 seconds.

**THE TABLE STRUCTURE:::**

```
> DESCRIBE tbl;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ...         | ...          | ...  | ... | ...     | ...            |
| created_at  | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The table contains 10,000,000+ rows

---

**THE INDEXES IN THE TABLE:::**

```
> SHOW INDEX IN tbl;
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tbl   |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | id          | A         |    10000545 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tbl   |          1 | created_at |            1 | created_at  | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**THE SQL UNDER CONCERN:::** Finding min-max DateTime of last 10k entries

```
SELECT 
    min(created_at), 
    max(created_at) 
FROM tbl 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 10000
```

---

**THE CONCERN:::** First query is always taking 2+ seconds to complete. After the first select, all subsequent query calls take less than 0.001 seconds to complete unless a new row gets inserted into the table.

First call in 2.06 seconds:

```
> SELECT min(created_at), max(created_at) FROM tbl USE INDEX (created_at) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10000;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| min(created_at)     | max(created_at)     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2010-01-01 00:00:00 | 2015-12-28 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (2.06 sec)
```

Subsequent calls in 0.00 seconds:

```
> SELECT min(created_at), max(created_at) FROM tbl USE INDEX (created_at) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10000;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| min(created_at)     | max(created_at)     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2010-01-01 00:00:00 | 2015-12-28 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Once a new row gets added into the table, it again takes 2+ seconds to complete and then all subsequent query calls take less than 0.001 seconds to complete.

I understand that the indexes get reshuffled every time a new row is inserted. So that's ok. However, my goal is to ***improve the first query time to less than a few milliseconds*** as taking 2+ seconds per query in a frequently updating system degrades the performance way too heavily.

---

**THE EXPLANATION OF THE QUERY PLAN:::** The explain statement shows that the query is going through almost all the rows of the table. So i am guessing i have room to improve by indexes. But what should i index?

```
> EXPLAIN SELECT min(created_at), max(created_at) FROM tbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10000;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl   | index | NULL          | created_at | 9       | NULL | 10000545 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your query will be faster just taking off `ORDER BY created_at DESC` if your query is using just grouping functions you don't need the order by clause

Comment: are you trying to limit the aggregate by the first 10k rows via PK id ? How often is this run? It is not like min(x) matters after day 1

Comment: @JorgeCampos i made a mistake in typing the query.... my bad..... the SQL should be `ORDER BY id DESC` instead of `ORDER BY created_at`.... i need the `ORDER BY id DESC` to imply the **last 10k** rows

Comment: @Drew let's say the query runs once every 10 minutes. This is how we are pulling analytics for our system at every 10 minutes interval.

Comment: It's a balancing act. Normalization, versus excusable de-norm

Comment: I have an pretty nasty idea here. you create an auxiliary table with just the two field max_created_at and min_created_at then you run your query one time to fill it the first time. Then you add on your table a trigger (before or after insert) that wil check if the created_at field is bigger and lesser than the fields on the auxiliary table if so just update it on the auxiliary table. Then your query will be on this auxiliary table with just ONE row. I think this would solve your problem, it is not pretty but it will work. If you decid to use this idea let me know, I will add it as an answer.

Comment: Your puzzle over "slow once, then always fast" -- The first time is fetching stuff from disk.  The subsequent times are either finding the data in cache or it is using the Query Cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original query does not return "the minimum/maximum date from the last 10000 entries"; the `LIMIT` applies after the aggregate functions are processed, so you're asking "Give me the max/min date, then limit that to the first 10k"... And there is only one row.

You must use a subquery for this:

```
SELECT min(created_at), max(created_at)
FROM (SELECT created_at
      FROM my_table
      ORDER BY id
      LIMIT 10000) subtable;
```

Your best bet is an index on `(id, created_at)`, because the subquery will then only need to traverse the index, and then the min/max query only needs to sort over 10k elements.

Comment: You can check that you're not limiting the min/max as you expect by doing `SELECT min(id), max(id) FROM my_table ORDER_BY id LIMIT 10000`. If it worked as you expect, you'd be getting "990000-1000000", but you'll get "1-1000000".

Comment: you, my friend, are a genius... that's a very sharp observation. It was indeed a bug in the SQL. With the corrected SQL, my query is taking less than 0.01 seconds.... thanks :)